# Question regarding transcendence degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

So, we know a theorem:

Fields with some characteristics and transcendence degree are isomorphic.

I am puzzled whether the generalization of this would be true :

Let $K,L$ be fields and $M$ be a subfield of both. Let $K$ have transcendence degree $n$ over $M$ and let $L$ have transcendence degree $m$ over $M$. If $n \leq m$ then there is a monomorphism from $K$ to $L$, i.e. $K$ can be regarded as a subfield of $L$.

Provided this is true, we would have that our theorem easily follows....

Comment: **Algebraically closed** fields with same characteristic and transcendence degree are isomorphic.

Comment: @KennyLau More precisely, you mean field extensions of an algebraically closed field, I suppose

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the theorem you mention is true only for algebraically closed fields, not general fields. Your generalization is also true if you assume $K$ and $L$ are algebraically closed (proof sketch: pick a transcendence basis $B$ for $K$ over $M$, get an embedding $M(B)\to L$ using the assumption that $n\leq m$, and then extend this embedding to $K$ since $K$ is algebraic over $M(B)$ and $L$ is algebraically closed).  The original theorem does *not* "easily follow" from this statement, though, and I'm not sure why you think it does.